# Evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{x}^{2x-1}dydx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{x}^{2x-1}dydx$$

[image]$$

**My attempt:**

$$I_1:=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{x}^{2x-1}dydx$$

$$=\int_{-1}^{1}\bigg[\int_{x}^{2x-1}dy\bigg]dx$$

$$=\int_{-1}^{1}\bigg(x-1\bigg)dx=\boxed{\color{red}{-2}}$$

Now I need to evaluate with changing the limis:

$$I_2:=\int_{-3}^{-1}\int_{-1}^{\frac{y+1}{2}}dxdy+\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{y}^{\frac{y+1}{2}}dxdy$$

> 1) Is it ok that before changing the limits the area is negative?
>
> 2) The new limits that I have done are correct?

Comment: $\int_{-1}^1 \int_{x}^{2x-1} \mathrm dy \mathrm dy = -2$ is correct. What do you mean with the second integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the limits:

> $$I_2=\int_{-3}^{-1}\int_{-1}^{\frac{y+1}{2}}dxdy+\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{y}^{\frac{y+1}{2}}dxdy$$

$$=\underbrace{\int_{-3}^{-1}\bigg(\frac{y+1}{2}+1\bigg)}_{=\color{blue}1}dy+\underbrace{\int_{-1}^{1}\bigg(\frac{y+1}{2}-y\bigg)}_{=\color{blue}1}dy$$
$$$$

$$\Longrightarrow=1+1=2$$

Answer (score 1):

1. Your first integral should be
   $$\int_{-1}^t \int_{2x-1}^{x}dy\,dx$$

because $2x - 1 < x$ for $x \in [-1,1]$

With that, the result is positive

2. Your second integral is correct